# Options and Configuration for console logging - how does it work in source code?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-logging

I'm trying to implement my own custom logger. I've been looking at the implementation of the Console Logger of microsoft.

You can configure the [ConsoleLoggerOptions](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerOptions.cs) in AppSettings like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": true,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
    },
    "Console": {
      "DisableColors": true
    }
}
```

Looking at AddConsole() extension: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerFactoryExtensions.cs#L18

How does the internal works for the Options? Where does it "bind" it with 'Console', where does it go from ConsoleLoggerOptions to Console?

I just don't understand after this point. Just adding the Options to services just 'works'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i dug a bit deeper:

ConsoleLoggerProvider has a provider alias which renames it to "Console":
https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProvider.cs#L14

And the configuration gets added based on the alias name:
https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/55518d79834d3319c91f40b449d028338b129ed6/src/Logging/Logging.Configuration/src/LoggerProviderConfigurationFactory.cs#L27

pretty well hidden imo